# Lasso-ability on leaflet heatmap

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a `shiny` app which displayes a `leaflet` heatmap. I would like to know if is possible to use a lasso like in  [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhZqfbdNg7w&ab_channel=JonathanMacDonald) to select certain data points.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
# ui object

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel(p("Spatial app", style = "color:#3474A7")),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            leafletOutput("map"),
            DTOutput("table1") 

        )
    )
)

# server()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$map<-renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(quakes) %>%
            addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.DarkMatter) %>%
            setView( 178, -20, 5 ) %>%
            addHeatmap(
                lng = ~long, lat = ~lat, intensity = ~mag,
                blur = 20, max = 0.05, radius = 15
            ) %>% 
            addCircleMarkers(lng = quakes$long, lat = quakes$lat, 
                             fillOpacity = 0, weight = 0,
                             popup = paste("Depth:", quakes$depth, "<br>",
                                           "Stations:", quakes$stations),
                             labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = TRUE)) 
    })
    
    
}

# shinyApp()
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```